# Matplotlib Import Error: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not WindowsPath

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pip

While I failed to import matplotlib.pyplot, I discovered that I could not even import matplotlib.

I am using pip, matplotlib 3.4.3 and python 3.9.5.

Here is the traceback for `import matplotlib`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\xtzha\Desktop\UN Online Volunteer\GIS\Data\TZ_2015-16_DHS_08122021_1325_155740\TZBR7BDT\check.py", line 6, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "C:\Users\xtzha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 822, in <module>
    rcParamsDefault = _rc_params_in_file(
  File "C:\Users\xtzha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 727, in _rc_params_in_file
    with _open_file_or_url(fname) as fd:
  File "C:\Users\xtzha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\xtzha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 701, in _open_file_or_url
    fname = os.path.expanduser(fname)
  File "C:\Users\xtzha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ntpath.py", line 293, in expanduser
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not WindowsPath
```

*I am just wondering if I could import matplotlib without downgrading it.*

P.s.
I tried to install lower versions of matplotlib but I could not because of the following error:

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\xtzha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\xtzha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3wyvt9m9\\matplotlib_f7637efda90a425e98d8a380e709b5c3\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\xtzha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3wyvt9m9\\matplotlib_f7637efda90a425e98d8a380e709b5c3\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\xtzha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-gxef4izq'
         cwd: C:\Users\xtzha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3wyvt9m9\matplotlib_f7637efda90a425e98d8a380e709b5c3\
    Complete output (61 lines):
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [2.2.3]
                    python: yes [3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021,
                            17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]]
                  platform: yes [win32]

    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                     numpy: yes [version 1.19.3]
          install_requires: yes [handled by setuptools]
                    libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]
                  freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype
                            (freetype2\ft2build.h) could not be found.  You may
                            need to install the development package.]
                       png: no  [The C/C++ header for png (png.h) could not be
                            found.  You may need to install the development
                            package.]
                     qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'libqhull' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]

    OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
               sample_data: yes [installing]
                  toolkits: yes [installing]
                     tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
            toolkits_tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                    macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                    qt5agg: no  [PySide2 not found; PyQt5 not found]
                    qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
                   gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
                 gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                    gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                     tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                            Tk]
                     wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                       gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                       agg: yes [installing]
                     cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
                 windowing: yes [installing]

    OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                    dvipng: no
               ghostscript: no
                     latex: no
                   pdftops: no

    OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                      dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    ============================================================================
                            * The following required packages can not be built:
                            * freetype, png
                            * Please check http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packa
                            * ges/freetype.htm for instructions to install
                            * freetype
                            * Please check http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packa
                            * ges/libpng.htm for instructions to install png
    ----------------------------------------
```

The same message still occur even when I installed freetype and png packages, which further discourages me from downgrading maplotlib. Is there any way to resolve this importing issue without downgrading matplotlib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you'll need to do a bit of downloading on your own.

From the error message, you at least need to download the headers for [freetype](https://www.freetype.org/) and [png](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libpng.htm) (The links are indications only. Please read further into them before deciding whether they match your needs and whether you trust them).

Comment: So do you suggest that I downgrade matplotlib to resolve the import error?

Comment: Yes, for now you should downgrade, I think. If it doesn't work, then I'm out of solutions...